# Why my SD Card not marked as removable?

Tags: sd-card, card-reader

My SD card in the card reader detected as mmcblk0

```
/sys/block/mmcblk0 -> ../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:01:00.0/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0
```

but it's not marked as **removable**

```
$ cat /sys/block/mmcblk0/removable
0
```

I have found a lot of issues across the internet related to this because the drive is not recognized as removable but unable to find a solution.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

$ lsmod |egrep 'mmc|sdhci|ricoh'
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         36864  0
rtsx_pci              106496  1 rtsx_pci_sdmmc

$ ls -la /sys/block/mmcblk0/
загалом 0
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root    0 мар 22 21:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 мар 22 21:46 ..
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 alignment_offset
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 мар 22 21:46 bdi -> ../../../../../../../../../virtual/bdi/179:0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 capability
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 dev
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 мар 22 21:46 device -> ../../../mmc0:0001
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 discard_alignment
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 diskseq
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 events
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 events_async
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 events_poll_msecs
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 ext_range
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 force_ro
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 hidden
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 мар 22 21:46 holders
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 inflight
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 мар 22 21:46 integrity
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 мар 22 21:46 mq
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 мар 22 21:46 power
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 мар 22 21:46 queue
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 range
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 removable
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 ro
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 size
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 мар 22 21:46 slaves
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 stat
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 мар 22 21:46 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../../../../class/block
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 мар 22 21:46 trace
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 мар 22 21:46 uevent
```

It's a built-in card reader in the hp pavilion notebook

I'm not sure which additional information I can provide.

UPD 2023-03-23: such behavior prevents normal operation of some programs which should work with removable media only, for example key storages, or bootable flash writers which relies on this flag.

- WoeUSB-ng don't show such disk in the list of available to write to, also refuses to work with even if forced. You can see this python function for example https://github.com/WoeUSB/WoeUSB-ng/blob/18e8918f75af26c0258a5b5f7bdb13acb76611eb/WoeUSB/list_devices.py#L46

Comment: A good start to any question is what commands you have tried and the results of the commands.

Comment: @David all commands I have tried is in the code block, but it's more getting information. Unfortunately I have no idea how can I change this behavior. I suspect, then, there is a configuration file somewhere with rules for determining which drives are removable and which are not but I can't find nothing about that.

Comment: I've never checked my inserted SD cards. Does it prevent any operation? Like read or write?

Comment: @kanehekili such behavior prevents normal operation of some programs which should work with removable media only, for example key storages, or bootable flash writers which relies on this flag.